# Yosemite 10.10.3 crashing often

Tags: macos, crash, performance

I've only been using my MBPr for a few weeks and it's been crashing often. It'll freeze and then either restart on its own, or what's often the case, need a hard reset. It started doing this on the second day. Currently, I've got Bootcamp going with Windows 8.1. I've noticed, though, that the crashing occurs way more while on OS X.

I've tried:

- resetting NVRAM and SMC
- reinstalling Yosemite

What I've done on my Mac as of recently re: Bootcamp are:

- Install 8.1 through BCA
- Remove Windows partition because I realized that I need a larger Windows partition
- Reinstalled 8.1. through BCA

I've noticed that crashes are more frequent when viewing videos (on VLC) and/or when playing music (iTunes, Spotify) but there also very random instances while browsing (used both Safari and Chrome) and just earlier when I used a new printer.

This is the log from the most recent crash (around 5 minutes before and until the crash):

```
5/20/15 7:53:54.000 PM kernel[0]: process steam_osx[352] caught causing excessive wakeups. EXC_RESOURCE supressed due to audio playback
5/20/15 7:54:30.000 PM kernel[0]: process gameoverlayui[381] caught causing excessive wakeups. EXC_RESOURCE supressed due to audio playback
5/20/15 7:59:44.345 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.345 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.345 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.345 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.345 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.345 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.381 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.381 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.381 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.381 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.381 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.381 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.453 PM identityservicesd[235]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fc3b1741aa0>: notification observer: com.apple.iChat   notification: __CFNotification 0x7fc3b153c4c0 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
5/20/15 7:59:44.453 PM imagent[256]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7ff270d24c90>: notification observer: com.apple.FaceTime   notification: __CFNotification 0x7ff270d14b30 {name = _NSDoNotDisturbDisabledNotification}
5/20/15 7:59:44.464 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.465 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.465 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.465 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.465 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.465 PM WindowServer[138]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 76587
5/20/15 7:59:44.480 PM identityservicesd[235]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fc3b1741aa0>:    NC Disabled: NO
5/20/15 7:59:44.480 PM imagent[256]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7ff270d24c90>:    NC Disabled: NO
5/20/15 7:59:44.487 PM identityservicesd[235]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fc3b1741aa0>:   DND Enabled: NO
5/20/15 7:59:44.487 PM imagent[256]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7ff270d24c90>:   DND Enabled: NO
5/20/15 7:59:44.487 PM imagent[256]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7ff270d24c90>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
"com.apple.ess",
"com.apple.private.ac"
))
5/20/15 7:59:44.487 PM identityservicesd[235]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7fc3b1741aa0>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
"com.apple.private.alloy.icloudpairing",
"com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.encryption",
"com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity",
"com.apple.private.alloy.idstransfers",
"com.apple.private.ids",
"com.apple.private.alloy.phonecontinuity",
"com.apple.ess",
"com.apple.madrid",
"com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.auth",
"com.apple.private.ac",
"com.apple.private.alloy.idsremoteurlconnection",
"com.apple.private.alloy.sms",
"com.apple.private.alloy.screensharing",
"com.apple.private.alloy.maps",
"com.apple.private.alloy.callhistorysync",
"com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.tethering"
))
5/20/15 7:59:51.699 PM ipcserver[389]: Valve Steam ipcserver started: 1.04
5/20/15 7:59:54.053 PM storeaccountd[297]: AccountServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fdd9363bf80> connection from pid 390 with interface <AccountServiceInterface: 0x7fdd93636510> (PID 390)
5/20/15 7:59:54.112 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/20/15 7:59:54.215 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/20/15 7:59:54.241 PM com.apple.iCloudHelper[395]: objc[395]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
5/20/15 7:59:54.249 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/20/15 7:59:54.590 PM locationd[74]: Couldn't find a requirement string for masquerading client /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Parsec.framework
5/20/15 7:59:54.591 PM locationd[74]: could not get apple languages array, assuming english
5/20/15 7:59:54.702 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/20/15 7:59:54.772 PM Safari[390]: [AOSAccounts] : [IsAccountKeyChainActive] : had error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.security.sos.error error 2 - Remote error : The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (com.apple.security.sos.error error 2 - Public Key not available - failed to register before call))
5/20/15 8:00:05.099 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/20/15 8:00:20.113 PM networkd[188]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.397 setting source application without entitlement
5/20/15 8:00:21.456 PM networkd[188]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.397 setting source application without entitlement
5/20/15 8:00:56.092 PM lsuseractivityd[234]: -[LSUserActivityClientProcess doUpdateUserActivityInfo:makeCurrent:completionHandler:], refusing to register user activity from client, and returning error Error Domain=LSContinuityErrorDomain Code=-108 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSContinuityErrorDomain error -108.)" for item <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7f8901e138d0> A4F333F7-7AD4-4C0B-8A2E-893BDEB00D17 NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb (LSUserActivityClientProcess.m #1148)
5/20/15 8:01:25.510 PM com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper[401]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper. Errno:1
5/20/15 8:01:25.513 PM com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper[401]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper. Errno:1
5/20/15 8:01:25.981 PM sandboxd[402]: ([401]) com.apple.Safari(401) deny file-issue-extension /Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper
5/20/15 8:01:26.065 PM sandboxd[402]: ([401]) com.apple.Safari(401) deny file-issue-extension /Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper
5/20/15 8:01:26.266 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[72]: Session 100023 created
5/20/15 8:01:30.630 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[397]: Ignoring controlTimebase set by client because AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer was added to a synchronizer
5/20/15 8:02:01.907 PM networkd[188]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.397 setting source application without entitlement
5/20/15 8:02:02.414 PM networkd[188]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.397 setting source application without entitlement
5/20/15 8:02:02.599 PM networkd[188]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.397 setting source application without entitlement
5/20/15 8:02:42.039 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[405]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
5/20/15 8:02:42.906 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/20/15 8:02:42.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(406) deny file-issue-extension /Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite
5/20/15 8:02:42.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(406) deny mach-lookup com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache
5/20/15 8:02:42.929 PM QuickLookSatellite[406]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite. Errno:1
5/20/15 8:02:42.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(406) deny file-issue-extension /Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite
5/20/15 8:02:42.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(406) deny mach-lookup com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache
5/20/15 8:02:42.930 PM QuickLookSatellite[406]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/Kim/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite. Errno:1
5/20/15 8:02:43.033 PM QuickLookSatellite[406]: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
5/20/15 8:02:43.033 PM QuickLookSatellite[406]: Invalid Connection ID 0
5/20/15 8:03:07.590 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[298]: Error -60005 creating authorization
5/20/15 8:03:10.015 PM com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[413]: Metadata.framework [Error]: couldn't get the client port
5/20/15 8:03:10.103 PM com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService[413]: assertion failed: 14D136: libxpc.dylib + 62495 [D35D0DB2-D7BD-3BE4-8378-062BFE545E1D]: 0x89
5/20/15 8:03:10.409 PM Pages[408]: NSWindow does not support utility styleMask 0x10
5/20/15 8:03:42.409 PM lsuseractivityd[234]: -[LSUserActivityClientProcess doUpdateUserActivityInfo:makeCurrent:completionHandler:], refusing to register user activity from client, and returning error Error Domain=LSContinuityErrorDomain Code=-108 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSContinuityErrorDomain error -108.)" for item <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7f8901c15470> FB067475-03AF-4C42-93E5-845DA5643F0E NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb (LSUserActivityClientProcess.m #1148)
5/20/15 8:05:12.298 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
```

I'm really at a loss to what might be going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I tried to reinstall Yosemite but it crashed halfway through so I took it to a Service Centre. They tested the hardware and said it passed all of their tests. They reinstalled Yosemite and now that I've got it back, it still crashes. I've isolated some apps that were crashing, even weeded out the Spigot adware and all that but random crashes still happen. I keep checking the console logs just before I had to reset and the logs are different each time so I'm having a hard time isolating the problem. Is Yosemite really this unstable?

Update: I took the unit to an authorized service center. They cleared it of any hardware issues and reinstalled Yosemite. When I got it back, the crashing continued. I have now updated to 10.10.4.

I've noticed that crashes only occur when I'm connected to the internet. It's stable when I am offline. Everytime a crash happens, I check the console but the messages before the crash are different each time which has made it difficult to isolate the problem. I have noticed though that awdd crashes very often, I get the deny file-read-data /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security-common.plist often from WebKit.Content, cloud, and a lot of other core apps (i have tried to locate this plist but have been unable to find the exact file) and WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.4 instead of 10.10.4. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number. from a lot of apps (Firefox, MS Office, etc.).

My most recent kernel panic report is:

```
Wed Jul  1 21:08:40 2015


*** MCA Error Report ***
CPU Machine Check Architecture Error Dump (CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5287U CPU @ 2.90GHz, CPUID: 0x306D4)
Core: 0
  IA32_MC3_STATUS=0xBE00000000800400
  IA32_MC3_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC3_ADDR=0xFFFFFF7FA05B656C
  IA32_MC3_MISC=0xFFFFFF7FA05B656C
Core: 0
  IA32_MC4_STATUS=0xBE00000000800400
  IA32_MC4_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC4_ADDR=0xFFFFFF7FA05B656C
  IA32_MC4_MISC=0xFFFFFF7FA05B656C
Core: 0
  IA32_MC5_STATUS=0xEE0000000040110B
  IA32_MC5_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC5_ADDR=0xFF7075C0
  IA32_MC5_MISC=0x13880000086
Core: 0
  IA32_MC6_STATUS=0xEE0000000040110B
  IA32_MC6_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC6_ADDR=0xFF70FBC0
  IA32_MC6_MISC=0x3880000086






System Profile:
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.5f8 15969, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500.28 GB
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
```

The panic reports I get look pretty much all look like this. 4 cores info, the system profile and nothing after.

Comment: Have you tried logging in from a different User account to see if the same issues are present?

Comment: @Ender Yes and it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me a lot when I close a YouTube tab in Safari. When it happens, it's instant. The system is still running. I can move the pointer. But otherwise the entire screen freezes. If I'm lucky it unfreezes in a fraction of a minute. If I'm unlucky it doesn't do that and I have to force a reboot.

I've linked it to this message:

```
5/20/15 8:01:30.630 PM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[397]: Ignoring controlTimebase set by client because AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer was added to a synchronizer
```

The message itself doesn't look concerning. But it does tend to appear at the exact time of a freeze. There's probably something AV-related going on, that also generates that message. I actually found this thread and several others by searching for that message. They're all about the freeze.

Remember com.apple.WebKit.WebContent is the name of the entire process. Lots of libraries are loaded in that process, WebKit being only one of them. It also doesn't mean other processes (like VLC or iTunes, as mentioned in the original post) can't do the same thing. An AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer is a part of AVFoundation that can be put somewhere in a window to display video, for one thing.